# Update Oracle table based on nested select incl. package function

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, sql-update

I have a query which calls a function in a package to create a percentage value as a sum of about 30 columns.

What I'd like to do is update each row based on the "sum of counted columns" as a percentage.

The select query is:

```
SELECT
checklist_id,
row_status,
eba_cm_checklist_std.get_row_percent_complete(pc.id,pc.checklist_id,pc.max_col_num) AS percent_complete
FROM
(
    SELECT
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(id)
            FROM
                eba_cm_checklist_columns
            WHERE
                checklist_id = r.checklist_id
        ) AS max_col_num,
        r.*
    FROM
        eba_cm_checklist_rows r
    ORDER BY
        r.row_order,
        r.name
) pc
```

and the package.function that creates the percentage is "eba_cm_checklist_std.get_row_percent_complete".

The query outputs the following:

```
 checklist_id                           row_status  percent_complete
 97176759931088640236098007249022291412 Red         0
 97176759931071715274623402440576404948 Red         0
 97176759931071715274623402440576404948 Red         0
 97176759931071715274623402440576404948 Red         0
 97176759931088640236098007249022291412 Red         0
 97176759931088640236098007249022291412 Red         0
 97176759931081386681180319473974054356 Grey        100
 97176759931051163535689953744606399956 Grey        100
```

The difficulty I'm having is that the expression is using a nested select statement based on the output of a function and I can't get my head around how to update the physical "eba_cm_checklist_rows" table based on the output of the query.

Basically, I want to do the following:

```
 update set row_status = 'Green' where percent_complete = 100
```

Comment: `count(*)` counts all rows, but `count(col)` only counts rows where col is not null.

Comment: Ok, I've substituted  `count(*)` for `count(id)`   (id is unique/pk for each row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use bulk select/update:

```
declare
  type t_rid_arr is table of rowid index by pls_integer;
  type t_row_status_arr is table of eba_cm_checklist_rows.row_status%type index by pls_integer;
  type t_percent_complete_arr is table of number index by pls_integer;

  l_rid_arr t_rid_arr;
  l_row_status_arr t_row_status_arr;
  l_percent_complete_arr t_percent_complete_arr;
begin
  SELECT
    rid,
    row_status,
    eba_cm_checklist_std.get_row_percent_complete(pc.id,pc.checklist_id,pc.max_col_num) AS percent_complete
  bulk collect into 
    l_rid_arr,
    l_row_status_arr,
    l_percent_complete_arr
  FROM (
    SELECT r.rowid as rid, 
           r.*,
           count(*) over(partition by checklist_id) AS max_col_num
      FROM eba_cm_checklist_rows r
     ) pc;

  forall i in 1..l_rid_arr.count 
     update eba_cm_checklist_rows
        set row_status = case when l_percent_complete_arr(i) = 100 then 'Green' else row_status end
      where rowid = l_rid_arr(i);
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks Rusty.  'PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.'  However, when I check the rows, the row_status hasn't changed.  I can't see why that would be!

Comment: Try to replace rowid with your primary key. Check type of percent_complete. Is it number?

Comment: I've replaced all instances of `rowid` with `id` (the pk for the table) and additionally used `to_number(l_percent_complete_arr(i)) = 100`  - still the same, executes successfully but doesn't seem to be updating anything.  Modified PL/SQL here: http://pastebin.com/RnY8d77F in case I'm doing something obviosuly wrong!

Comment: Sorry, posted to wrong place before - Does select return values that you are expecting to see?

Comment: No, the select shows the original values, no changes made.

Comment: Also, very stangely seems to break the front end - can no longer change the "percentage" of existing rows via the application front end but can continue to add new rows and change their status.  Very odd.  I think I'd like to try using a CTE to solve this as it seems a bit more straightforward.

Comment: Does sql  from my sample return rows with percent_complete = 100 ?

Comment: The SQL returns all rows regardless of the value in percent_complete.

Comment: Would help if I was looking at the right database!  Thanks Rusty, this solution does appear to be working!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136557/discussion-between-huskie69-and-rusty).

Answer (score 1):

you could try to use CTE and SUM() OVER() function, hope you find it useful.

Comment: A CTE looks like the way to go, thanks! (not heard of this feature before).  Just trying to figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
merge into eba_cm_checklist_rows trg
using (
SELECT
rid,
checklist_id,
row_status,
eba_cm_checklist_std.get_row_percent_complete(pc.id,pc.checklist_id,pc.max_col_num) AS percent_complete
FROM
(
    SELECT r.rowid as rid, 
           r.*,
           count(*) over(partition by checklist_id) AS max_col_num
      FROM eba_cm_checklist_rows r
) pc
) src
on (trg.rowid = src.rid)
when matched then update set row_status = 'Green' where percent_complete = 100;
```

I don't like the idea to use function inside the SQL - it's probably could be replaced with normal SQL.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting 'ORA-04091: table CHECKLIST.EBA_CM_CHECKLIST_ROWS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "CHECKLIST.EBA_CM_CHECKLIST_STD", line 44'

Comment: There's a trigger on this table which calls a function (CHECKLIST.EBA_CM_CHECKLIST_STD.create_checklist_history) to update a 'history' table recording any changes made...

Comment: well, I don't know what this function is doing. Can you post source please?

Comment: Sure Rusty - it's quite long so I've added it to pastebin:  http://pastebin.com/raw/A6y2ZMBy

Comment: Additionally, here's the source to the package body eba_cm_checklist_std which contains the functions I'm using:  http://pastebin.com/raw/s3yw7PGK

Comment: Try another option I've posted

Comment: Does select return values that you are expecting to see?